# Azure Key Vault not allow access via private endpoint connection

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I've a azure web service (linux) and azure key vault.

i configure two private endpoint , to allow the communication between Azure Key Vault and Azure web app.

[image]

[image]

i set all permissions in `key vault's access policy` , i ve already added identiy managed in `the azure web app` and the two endpoint are in the same `virtual network`, but the app is unable to read the key vault reference

[image]

any idea to resolve that ?

EDIT  :

The access is allowed from private endpoint and selected networks

[image]

i don't want to put the **public ip** address of my web app in the firewall

i added the vnet in the key vault

[image]

Comment: Need error message.

Comment: @MattSmall i add details , can you please recheck ?

Comment: Please show the VNet/Firewall settings.

Comment: @MattSmall can you please help me

Comment: I think that the firewall is blocking requests.  When you enable the firewall, it blocks everything except the whitelisted address, including internal IPs.  With  private endpoint, the KV should have a private IP for internal use. 

Turn off the firewall and test to see if it works.  If it does, is the Key Vault also still accessible from the public?  I think it should not be accessible once the private endpoint is enabled.  If it not accessible from the public, but it is from the linux app service, you're configured properly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but if i disable the firewall, i will give access to all networks ? if i turn off the firewall , a message is showing : This key vault has associated private endpoints. By allowing access from all networks, the security provided by private endpoints will not be satisfied.

Comment: Interesting...  I know my network knowledge is lacking.  How about adding the KV to the same VNet as the private endpoint?

Comment: the KV have a private endpoint , also the web app , the two endpoint are in the same vnet , the web app can't get the secret value ( the same error )

Comment: In the screenshot above, the KV shows that it is not in the VNet.

Comment: @MattSmall , i add the screenshoot

Comment: Turn on logging and give me the complete error message from a request.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/howto-logging?tabs=azure-cli

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To allow your azure app service to access the Azure key vault with a private endpoint, you have to do the following steps:

1. Using [regional VNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#regional-vnet-integration) enables your app to access a private endpoint in your integrated virtual network.
2. [Establishing a private link connection to an existing key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/private-link-service?tabs=portal#establish-a-private-link-connection-to-an-existing-key-vault).
3. [Validating that the private link connection works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/private-link-service?tabs=portal#validate-that-the-private-link-connection-works). From your Azure app service console or kudu portal, you can validate that your application is connecting to your key vault over a private IP address and that they have the correct private DNS zone integration.
4. Add access policy of key vault for your Azure web app.

In this case, you can enable the firewall of the key vault via selecting the checkbox of the private endpoint and selected networks when you use the private link, read [Key Vault Firewall Enabled (Private Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/network-security#key-vault-firewall-enabled-private-link)).

Please note that when you [use Key Vault references.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options?WT.mc_id=ES-MVP-5003833%3FWT.mc_id%3DAZ-MVP-5003833#use-key-vault-references)

> Currently, Key Vault references won't work if your key vault is
> secured with service endpoints. To connect to a key vault by using
> virtual network integration, you need to call Key Vault in your
> application code.

You could read these wonderful [blog1](https://securecloud.blog/2020/05/22/app-service-key-vault-vnet-service-endpoint-access-options-explored-nodejs-runtime-examples/) and [blog2](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/04/22/Site-with-secure-backend-communication.html) for more details.

Comment: thanks for you repley , i already establish a private link connection and validate them using this tutorial : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/private-link-service?tabs=portal#validate-that-the-private-link-connection-works , but i want to know why i should use a regional vnet

Comment: also , i have a private endpoint , i think i can use reference

Comment: By default, Azure web app access from the Internet, if you want to access key vault with exposing the private endpoint of key vault only and don't need to put the public ip address of web app in the firewall, you need to gain access to the VNet from your web app. This required a vnet integration.

Comment: Thanks for you reply , i have a question , please : i ve activate a private endpoint connection in the web app , also a private endpoint in key vault (the same vnet) , i already test the key vault's private endpoint usong nslookup from a vm in the same network , so , i should use library to access key vault ?

Comment: It should be, anyway, you should use that Azure key vault URL because its FQDN will be resolved to the private IP address of the private endpoint. This will identify if you are accessing from a private VNet instead of from the public internet.

Comment: i use the url provided by the private dns ? or the public url ?

Comment: public Url like `https://yourkv.vault.azure.net/` if you followed that official steps.

Comment: in app setting reference , it's not working

Comment: I suggest calling Key Vault in your application code referring to the above blogs. BTW, you can verify If you remove the private endpoint for your web app because this will restrict inbound traffic to your web app.

Comment: i'am so confused , i'am sorry , i can't remove the private endpoint, but i would know if i can resolve the secret from key vault through private endpoint

Comment: At the beginning of this question, you said you have configured two service endpoints. I guess one is for the Azure web app, another is for your key vault on your side. If so, I just suggest removing the service endpoint setting on your app service. If you have validated that the private link connection works from your web app console. it means that you can resolve the secret from key vault through private endpoint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232668/discussion-between-quentin-merlin-and-nancy-xiong).

Comment: @NancyXiong In your 5/19 Answer, you provided a small reference stating:  "Currently, Key Vault references won't work if your key vault is secured with service endpoints. To connect to a key vault by using virtual network integration, you need to call Key Vault in your application code."  Is it possible to provide a link to that document?  I am trying to troubleshoot a Function App and Key Vault setup where both are secured by Private Endpoint, but KeyVault references are not working.  That quote makes it seem not possible?  Would like to read further.  Thanks very much.