# Is there any other way to get PrivateEndpointConnection for Key Vault?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

API from Microsoft not working. [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/{vaultName}/privateEndpointConnections?api-version=2021-10-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/%7BvaultName%7D/privateEndpointConnections?api-version=2021-10-01)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Key Vault not allow access via private endpoint connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67589490/azure-key-vault-not-allow-access-via-private-endpoint-connection)

Comment: [Integrate Key Vault with Azure Private Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/private-link-service?tabs=portal)

Answer (score 0):

The api you are trying without mentioning `privateendpoint` name to get the specified `privateendpoint` we need to mention the below `api` .

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/{vaultName}/privateEndpointConnections/{privateEndpointConnectionName}?api-version=2021-10-01
```

For more information please refer this [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION|MHSM Private Endpoint Connections - Get***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/managedhsm/mhsm-private-endpoint-connections/get)