# How can I put a private endpoint from a key vault in a logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-keyvault, azure-logic-app-standard

I have a logic App XXXXX and in the Application settings, I have a parameter that I want to put the key vault.

But I don't want to use this:
@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=XXXXXXXXXXXXX;SecretName=XXXXXXXXXXXXX)
because is not safe.

I want to use a private endpoint. How can I put the private endpoint, that I create in the key vault, inside of logic app?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How is @Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=XXXXXXXXXXXXX;SecretName=XXXXXXXXXXXXX)  not safe?  The connection is encrypted and the secret is read into the logic app at runtime.

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67589490/azure-key-vault-not-allow-access-via-private-endpoint-connection